# Establishing A is confused with “having established” the cause of A

Tags: comparisons

I have trouble understanding this sentence:

1. Establishing that a certain event occurred is confused with having established the cause of that event. (from an LSAT)

What is the implication for the sentence to have "having established" after "with"?

I was thinking how **1.** reveals a different nuance as opposed to:

2. Establishing that a certain event occurred is confused with establishing the cause of that event.

Could someone please help explain?

Thank you very much,

Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall structure of the sentence is "A is confused with B". "A" is the noun phrase "Establishing that a certain event occurred", while "B" is also a noun phrase "having established the cause of the event".

To establish in this context is to prove, and to confuse two things is to mistake one for the other. The writer is stating that somebody has mixed up two different things - A:proving that something happened, and B:proving what its cause was.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. A quick follow-up: based on what you've said, then 1. and 2. sentences above do not differ, correct?

Comment: The phrase "doing A" can refer to an action in the past. Your sentence 1 sounds like a review, where "establishing an event occurred" is in the past because it has already been done before the review was written. Sentence 1 sounds as though the proofs or non-proofs are in the past, while sentence 2 does not. Effectively they mean the same thing though, and a writer should not expect a reader to draw any conclusions from the change of tense.

Answer (score 1):

“Having established” signifies an outcome, whereas “establishing” signifies work in progress. Can’t be certain without a context, but most likely the given sentence aims to underscore the difference between **learning what happened** (a process) and **knowing why it happened** (an outcome).